# SharePoint User information update without UPS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to update user information like job title and department in SharePoint 2010 where User Profile Service is not configured.Any manual activity or PS-command will help

Comment: In addition to the PS script below, I have a timer job available here that will accomplish the same thing.  It is directed towards Foundation installations, but can be used in Standard/Enterprise as well - http://foundationsync.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 1):

The User Information List stores information about a user by having some metadata set up for the user. Some examples are Picture, Email, DisplayName, LoginName etc. ). Something to note is that when a user is granted access to a site, a new item will be created in the User Information List storing some information about the user.

In SharePoint content database, UserInfo table holds information about all the users for each site collection, AllUserData table Holds information about all the list items for each list, so I’m afraid that there is no need to synchronized them.

You can make use of the following powershell code to set the Department property of an user, you can change it according to your use, Pass the username and Department to be changed for an user,

```
  function Sync-SPUser([string]$userName, [string]$Department ) {
      Get-SPSite -Limit All | foreach {
        $web = $_.RootWeb
        if ($_.WebApplication.UseClaimsAuthentication) {
          $claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal $userName -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
          $user = $web | Get-SPUser -Identity $claim -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        } else {
          $user = $web | Get-SPUser -Identity $userName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        if ($user -ne $null) {
          $web | Set-SPUser -Identity $user -SyncFromAD

          $list = $web.Lists["User Information List"]
          $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
          $query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>$userName</Value></Eq></Where>"
          foreach ($item in $list.GetItems($query)) {
            $item["Department"] = $title
            $item.SystemUpdate()
          }
        }
        $web.Dispose()
        $_.Dispose()
      }
    }
```

Source,

1. http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/12/updating-sharepoint-2010-user-information/
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/759d3c83-3fed-4bfc-a591-e88ca40e9407/sharepoint-user-information-list

Comment: If you find my above answer is correct, please mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful to others :)